# Функция для перестановки и переименовывания столбцов в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм, в нем следующая структура:

```
Столбец Дат | Много столбцов с номерами | Те же столбцы с номерами но другими данными в строках.
```

Как можно сделать следующее:

```
Столбец дат | Столбец с номером | Столбец с номером и другими данными в строках | Столбец с номером | Столбец с номером и другими данными в строках | ..............
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Из верхего получить нижний

Comment: пример датафрейма приведите в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: @strawdog Добавил код

Comment: Я просил не код, а пример датафрейма, с которым вы уже работаете по переставлению колонок. Мне просто интересно, как у вас получаются колонки с одинаковыми именами.